# Grails Logging Config Ignored

Tags: tomcat, grails, logging, log4j

Log4j seems to be ignoring some of my Grails Logging settings in Config.groovy, but not others.  I am running Grails 2.2.1 on tomcat.

I have set up my config file (below) to log all error and higher messages to the console (which is mapped to catalina.out in tomcat), all info and higher messages in the parse, schedule, and syndicate packages to master.log, and all debug an higher messages in the parse, schedule, and syndicate packages to their respective parse, schedule, and syndicate logs.

All files mentioned in the appenders section are being created in the appropriate locations, and receiving log messages.  However, **master.log is receiving debug messages**, and both master.log and syndicate.log have **grown to 19GB in size**, when the config clearly limits them to 25MB...

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?  How could grails respect one line of my config and not the next?  The relevant section of my Config.groovy file is:

```
log4j = {
// Uncomment to override the default logging level across all
//   classes.
root {
      warn catalinaOut
}

appenders {
  // this line prevents all messages from being duplicated to stdout DONT DELETE
    console name: "stdout",
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "")
    console name: "catalinaOut",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%-5p [%d] %c{2} %m%n")
    file name: "dcsFileAppender",
                file: "logs/data-collection-system/master.log",
                maxFileSize: "25MB",in
                maxBackupIndex: 10,
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%-5p [%d] %c{2} %m%n")
    file name: "parseFileAppender",
                file: "logs/data-collection-system/parse.log",
                maxFileSize: "25MB",
                maxBackupIndex: 10,
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%-5p [%d] %c{2} %m%n")
    file name: "scheduleFileAppender",
                file: "logs/data-collection-system/schedule.log",
                maxFileSize: "25MB",
                maxBackupIndex: 10,
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%-5p [%d] %c{2} %m%n")
    file name: "syndicateFileAppender",
                file: "logs/data-collection-system/syndicate.log",
                maxFileSize: "25MB",
                maxBackupIndex: 10,
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%-5p [%d] %c{2} %m%n")
}

environments {
    production {
      info dcsFileAppender: ["com.progauge.icp.parse", "com.progauge.icp.schedule", "com.progauge.icp.syndicate"]
      all parseFileAppender: ["com.progauge.icp.parse"],
        scheduleFileAppender: ["com.progauge.icp.schedule"],
        syndicateFileAppender: ["com.progauge.icp.syndicate"]
    }
}
}
```

As a side note, I had to set the pattern for stdout to an empty string because I don't want standard console logging behavior, but setting the appender to null breaks my custom console logging, which I also don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three main issues with the configuration you have so far:

- log levels are set *per logger* - if you want to send different level messages from the same logger to different appenders then you need to set the logger to the most detailed level and then set a *threshold* on the relevant appender(s) to filter out messages that are at too fine a log level.
- if you want to limit the file size and make backups then you should use appenders of type `rollingFile` instead of `file`
- to suppress the default `stdout` appender you should use `'null'` (this is the four character string null as opposed to the `null` value, and defines a Log4J `NullAppender`, a sink that ignores any log messages written to it).

Try something more like this:

```groovy
log4j = {
  // Uncomment to override the default logging level across all
  // classes.
  root {
      warn 'catalinaOut'
  }

  appenders {
    // this line prevents all messages from being duplicated to stdout
    'null' name: "stdout"

    console name: "catalinaOut",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%-5p [%d] %c{2} %m%n")

    // threshold to make this appender only log INFO and higher messages
    rollingFile name: "dcsFileAppender",
                file: "logs/data-collection-system/master.log",
                maxFileSize: "25MB",
                maxBackupIndex: 10,
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%-5p [%d] %c{2} %m%n"),
                threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO

    rollingFile name: "parseFileAppender",
                file: "logs/data-collection-system/parse.log",
                maxFileSize: "25MB",
                maxBackupIndex: 10,
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%-5p [%d] %c{2} %m%n")
    rollingFile name: "scheduleFileAppender",
                file: "logs/data-collection-system/schedule.log",
                maxFileSize: "25MB",
                maxBackupIndex: 10,
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%-5p [%d] %c{2} %m%n")
    rollingFile name: "syndicateFileAppender",
                file: "logs/data-collection-system/syndicate.log",
                maxFileSize: "25MB",
                maxBackupIndex: 10,
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%-5p [%d] %c{2} %m%n")
  }

  environments {
    production {
      all parseFileAppender: ["com.progauge.icp.parse"],
        scheduleFileAppender: ["com.progauge.icp.schedule"],
        syndicateFileAppender: ["com.progauge.icp.syndicate"],
        dcsFileAppender: ["com.progauge.icp.parse", "com.progauge.icp.schedule", "com.progauge.icp.syndicate"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, the change to stdout killed all logging to the console, but the other two recommendations worked, and those were what I was concerned with.  Thank you.

Comment: @therealmitchconnors rather than try and suppress the default `stdout` appender entirely and create another console appender in its place it would be simpler just to say `console name:'stdout', layout:...` and use `stdout` instead of `catalinaOut`

Comment: the problem is that, when I do that, I get two instances of every log message that goes to the console: one through my configured logger, and one through grails' implicit default logger.

Comment: if you are using grails version `1.3.7` to avoid Tomcat to duplicate logging to stdout logger, you have to remove the `console` appender. `log4j { r ->         r.removeAppender('console')     }`